# Unable to start Tomcat Serverv7.012 in Eclipse

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, jakarta-ee, tomcat

I am very new to Java. I am trying to install Java EE since two days but I am facing a problem These are the steps that i have done..

Installed Java SE (set environment variable) and Java EE 7 SDK Bundles without JDK there on I downloaded Tomcat server 7.0. There after i downloaded the EE edition of Eclipse and installed Tomcat server.

But when i do I get the following error..

"Server Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost was unable to start within 60 seconds. If the server requires more time, try increasing the timeout in the server editor".

I tried the following

> Increased the timeout time in server.
>
> UN-installed  Tomcat server and reinstalled.
>
> restarted the PC
>
> shutdown down and started the batch file..
>
> the problems still persists..
> uninstalled entire java packages and tried the same again.

please help me to fix the problem.

Here is the console output..

```
Dec 15, 2013 9:49:11 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production 
environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Windows
\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin/client;C:/Program 
Files/Java/jre7/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/lib/i386;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows
\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\DMIX;C:\Program 
Files\latex\miktex\bin\;C:\Program Files\YOKOGAWA\IA\iPCS\Platform\Security\Program;H:\CENTUMVP
\HIS\Users\Program;H:\CENTUMVP\TOKUCHULIB;H:\CENTUMVP\ENG\Users\Program;C:\Program Files\YOKOGAWA
\IA\iPCS\Products\CENTUMVP\Program;H:\CENTUMVP\LIBRARY;H:\CENTUMVP\TokuchuLibTagd;H:\jaypee\ENGTOOL
\COMMON;H:\jaypee\ENGTOOL\Perl\bin;H:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\runtime\win32;H:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;H:\VS 2010 & Eclipse\eclipse-jee-kepler-SR1-win32\eclipse;;.

Dec 15, 2013 9:49:12 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]

Dec 15, 2013 9:49:12 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]

Dec 15, 2013 9:49:12 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 296 ms

Dec 15, 2013 9:49:12 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina

Dec 15, 2013 9:49:12 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.12

Dec 15, 2013 9:49:12 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]

Dec 15, 2013 9:49:12 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]

Dec 15, 2013 9:49:12 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 168 ms
```

Comment: Did you try so see the server console. I mean the server home page in browser. http://localhost:8080/

Comment: ya I did try initially, It was giving an error page, now it says 

Firefox can't find the server at www.localhost.com.